# Yii 1.1: static parameter in route

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting, url-routing, yii1.x

For the purpose of beautification I have a set of URL schemas like:

```
/alpha-action/...
/beta-action/...
/gamma-action/...
/delta-action/...
```

They are handled by the same controller and I wish by the same action like:

```
function actionAlphabet($letter, $param1)
```

What I want is to pass *static* parameter to action that would depend on the URL (syntax is made-up):

```
'alpha-action/<param1:.*>' => 'site/alphabet('alpha')',
'beta-action/<param1:.*>'  => 'site/alphabet('beta')',
'gamma-action/<param1:.*>' => 'site/alphabet('gamma')',
'delta-action/<param1:.*>' => 'site/alphabet('delta')'
```

Is it doable in Yii 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

I your case you can use params as a part of the pattern and use only one rule:

```
'<letter:\w+>-action/<param1:.*>' => 'site/alphabet',
```

But if you really want to create separate rules, you can use [`defaultParams`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule#defaultParams-detail) property to specify default value for params not available in pattern:

```
'alpha-action/<param1:.*>' => ['site/alphabet', 'defaultParams' => ['letter' => 'alpha']],
'beta-action/<param1:.*>'  => ['site/alphabet', 'defaultParams' => ['letter' => 'beta']],
'gamma-action/<param1:.*>' => ['site/alphabet', 'defaultParams' => ['letter' => 'gamma']],
'delta-action/<param1:.*>' => ['site/alphabet', 'defaultParams' => ['letter' => 'delta']],
```